# vertical align (center center) a slider doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Imagine #bg is my body, and I want to make the slider (slick slider center center) for every slides. The plugin already has advaptive height but I just coulnd't make it center center on #bg.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/obd45c4r/

I tried vertical align trick like

```
.vcenter {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

but it just doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flex to center the content vertically. like this

```
#bg{
   background:blue;
   width:100%;
   height: 600px;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

Check updated fiddle [HERE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/9543hn93/).

Read flex in detail [HERE](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/)

Comment: why height must be 600px? suppose it should be dynamic?

Comment: Yeah you can make it dynamic. I added 600px to show example that inner contents get centered vertically.

Comment: I found a hack, use 100vh, instead of 600px

Answer (score 0):

Please change slider class in CSS.
Add Following.

```
.slider {
 text-align : center
}
```

It will display in center with above class.

For jsfiddle demo please click [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/vatsal18/fd7xcgvt/1/)

Comment: Ok checking again.